# param robot_description not found by searchParam()

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, robot-description, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Melodic and I'm trying to create a launch file to run multiple Turtlebot3 that share a map. I have created a `one_robot.launch` file that launches a single robot, it looks like this:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" />
    <!-- @ REQUIRED @ -->
    <arg name="robot_name" />
    <arg name="x_pos" />
    <arg name="y_pos" />
    <arg name="z_pos" />

    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro' prefix:=$(arg multi_robot_name)" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg multi_robot_name)"/>
    </node>

    <!--spawner-->
    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
          args="-urdf -model $(arg robot_name) -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos)
          -param /$(arg robot_name)/robot_description"
    />

    <!--AMCL -->
    <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" args="scan:=scan">
        <remap from="static_map" to="/static_map"/>
        <param name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg x_pos)" />
        <param name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg y_pos)" />
        <param name="global_frame_id" value="map" />
        <param name="odom_frame_id" value="$(arg robot_name)/odom" />
        <param name="base_frame_id" value="$(arg robot_name)/base_link" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

I then run two istances of this file in `startup.launch`, which is:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" />
    <arg name="robot_1" value="robot_1" />
    <arg name="robot_2" value="robot_2" />
    <arg name="gazebo_gui" default="false" /> <!-- ACTIVATE GAZEBO GUI -->

    <!-- GAZEBO -->
    <include file="$(find learning_multirobot)/launch/includes/main_gazebo.launch">
        <arg name="world_name" value="$(find learning_multirobot)/worlds/turtlebot3_house.world"/>
        <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
        <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
        <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gazebo_gui)"/>
        <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
        <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
    </include>

    <!-- map server -->
    <node pkg="map_server" type="map_server" name="map_loader" args="$(find learning_navigation)/maps/mymap.yaml" />
    
    <!--robot 1-->
    <group ns="$(arg robot_1)">
        <include file="$(find learning_multirobot)/launch/one_robot.launch">
            <arg name="robot_name" value="$(arg robot_1)" />
            <arg name="x_pos" value="0" />
            <arg name="y_pos" value="0" />
            <arg name="z_pos" value="0" />
        </include>
    </group>

    <!--robot 2-->
    <group ns="$(arg robot_2)">
        <include file="$(find learning_multirobot)/launch/one_robot.launch">
            <arg name="robot_name" value="$(arg robot_2)" />
            <arg name="x_pos" value="-3" />
            <arg name="y_pos" value="1" />
            <arg name="z_pos" value="0" />
        </include>
    </group>

    <!-- RVIZ -->
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find learning_multirobot)/rviz/complete_config.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

What happens is that Rviz warns me that `RobotModel` can't be shown because the parameter `robot_description` doesn't seem to exist.

I checked if the TF tree was correct, and in fact it is: I won't post it because it would make this question too long, but from the `/map` root frame there are two tfs to `robot_1/odom` and `robot_2/odom`, which are then connected to their respective `base_link` and all the robot sensors.

Moreover, running `rosparam list` shows that both the robot_descriptions parameters exist under their respective namespaces, being robot_1 and robot_2, and **they are non-null**, being in fact the XML representation of the robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337079/param-robot_description-not-found-by-searchparam()/) by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What happens is that Rviz warns me that `RobotModel` can't be shown because the parameter `robot_description` doesn't seem to exist.

It doesn't, does it? There's only `robot_1/robot_description` and `robot_2/robot_description`.

> I checked if the TF tree was correct, and in fact it is: I won't post it because it would make this question too long, but from the `/map` root frame there are two tfs to `robot_1/odom` and `robot_2/odom`, which are then connected to their respective `base_link` and all the robot sensors.

The error RViz returns to you is (most likely) not about TF, but about the actual parameter.

> Moreover, running `rosparam list` shows that both the robot_descriptions parameters exist under their respective namespaces, being robot_1 and robot_2, and **they are non-null**, being in fact the XML representation of the robot.

Yes, but again: there is no `robot_description` in the global namespace, only in the `robot_1` and `robot_2` namespaces.

The last `.launch` file you show appears to start `rviz` in the global namespace, which is where RViz will look for `robot_description`. It won't look in any child namespaces.

You can probably make things work by configuring the `RobotModel` display with the `robot_1` or `robot_2` namespaces. That would allow you to visualise a single robot model. For multiple robots, you'd add multiple `RobotModel` displays, each with their own parameter configured.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-11-07**:
Hi, thanks for your reply. I have tried to edit the `TF Prefix` option of `RobotModel` in Rviz, but it still doesn't work. Is it what you meant? Otherwise I don't see any other way to load the model from the aforementioned namespaces

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-07**:\

> I have tried to edit the `TF Prefix` option of `RobotModel` in Rviz, but it still doesn't work. Is it what you meant?

No, that's not what I meant.

The `RobotModel` display allows you to configure the name of the parameter from which it should read the URDF. That is where you'll need to add the prefix.

So you'll have two `RobotModel`s: one with `robot_1/robot_description` as the parameter name, and one with `robot_2/robot_description`.

You will need to make sure to also add the TF Prefix to each I believe. But TF (with or without a prefix) is not involved in loading the model. It only comes into play *after* things have been loaded, to give the model its pose.

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-11-08**:
Thanks, I thought one of the two would have made the job, while instead you need to set Rviz's parameter `Robot description` to `robot_NUM/robot_description` **and also** the respective `TF Prefix`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-08**:
Yes.

The former tells the display where it can find the `robot_description` parameter.

The latter helps it find the correct transforms.

As I wrote earlier: they are both needed, but completely separate.